# Angular module injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I am trying to create a sample Angular app with .Net, just to get the idea how to connect two of them but I can not get rid of this injector::modulerr error. Tried variety of things, changing dependencies, removing empty brackets and so on but nothing changes. I have created plunker to keep this thread cleaner the link is below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5AHsUSrFib4dkiX6XjLY?p=preview

I think the error keeps coming from this one

```js
angular.module('angularTest', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', '$routeParams', '$httpProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $routeParams, $httpProvider) {
        console.log('1');
        $routeProvider.
            when('/routeOne', {
                templateUrl: 'routesDemo/one'
            })
            .when('/routeTwo/:donuts', {
                templateUrl: function (params) { return '/routesDemo/two?donuts=' + params.donuts }
            })
            .when('/routeThree', {
                templateUrl: 'routesDemo/three'
            })
            .when('/login?returnUrl', {
                templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
                controller: LoginController
            });
        console.log('2');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthHttpResponseInterceptor');
    }
]);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$routeParams` should be post fix with `Provider` as you can only use provider in config phase.

Also you should always define app only once then append it by using that module, recreating `angular.module` will flush the old app & new copy will treated as that module. In you service & controller you need to make change from `angular.module('angularTest',[])` to `angular.module('angularTest')`

Additionally you missed to add `'` on `LogInController`

```
  .when('/login?returnUrl', {
     templateUrl: '/Account/Login',
     controller: 'LoginController' //<--here added qoutes
  });
```

One last thing, you missed to add `AuthHttpResponseInterceptor.js` which was not recognize by the angular app and was throwing `AuthHttpResponseInterceptor` factory not defined.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CCdQXtRbEgro7xbzUNo5?p=preview)

Comment: I wasnt sure about $routeParams, since I am not using it directly in config it is not needed, am I right? Removing it, doesnt change anything. Also when I remove square brackets from angular.module('angularTest', []) it starts complaining that I missed it or forgot a dependency.

Comment: @DasBoot there are many mistakes in your code..let me collect them all..& I'm updating my answer with fix..

Comment: @DasBoot thats completed my analysis..I updated answer with working plunkr..do look at it..Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like the same plunker I gave or I am missing something :). Thanks for your time

Comment: @DasBoot ohh sorry..Thats my bad..look at my edit now..it should be clear to you now.

Comment: Also I had a mistake while bundling modules. After moving this config up solved all issues. Thanks for help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81463/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-dasboot).