# AngularJS Routing problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to route something using `angular-route.js` library, but I don't know how to do properly.

I would like to change a message when the browsers route change, but I get a lot of errors to do that.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="my-app">
  <head>
    <title>Angular controllers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- AngularJS and JQuery include.  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <p> <a href="#ShowOrder/1556">Order 1556</a> </p>
      <p> <a href="#ShowOrder/1667">Order 1667</a> </p>
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function (){
  var app = angular.module('my-app', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config (['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when ('/ShowOrder/:orderId', {
      templateUrl           : 'show-order.html',
      controller            : 'ShowOrderCtrl'
    });
  }]);

  app.controller ('ShowOrderCtrl', ['$routeParams', '$scope', function ($routeParams, $scope){
    $scope.order = $routeParams.orderId;
  }]);
})();
```

**show-order.html**

```
<h2>Order #{{order}}</h2>

Here are the details for order <b>#{{order}}</b>.
```

**Error code**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/ismaelmoral/GitHub/angularjs-controllers/show-order.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10506sendReq @ angular.js:10325$get.serverRequest @ angular.js:10037processQueue @ angular.js:14551(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14567$get.Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15830$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15641$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15935bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1624invoke @ angular.js:4443doBootstrap @ angular.js:1622bootstrap @ angular.js:1642angularInit @ angular.js:1536(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28289x.Callbacks.l @ jquery.min.js:4x.Callbacks.c.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4x.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:4S @ jquery.min.js:4
angular.js:12314 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///Users/ismaelmoral/GitHub/angularjs-controllers/show-order.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at
```

Comment: Are you running this from `localhost`?  I see that you are trying to load a view that triggers a cross origin error.  Try setting up a server for your `localhost` to get rid of the error, or, simply move the view's (`html`) location to the same location as your script.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah All the files are in the same directory.

Comment: Can you serve this from a web server? It looks like you are just loading the index as a file in your browser, and your browser isn't allowing a XMLHttpRequest on a 'file://' protocol. It wants an http request.

Comment: I've tested your code locally and it works as expected. As mentioned use a web server so you can access it at `localhost`. A simple server is for example [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). Once installed just run `serve` in your project folder.

Comment: Its same as like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31035013/2435473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact you are running your app off the file system. Most browsers restrict `XMLHttpRequest` calls when using the `file://` protocol.

`angular-route.js` templates are accessed via `XMLHttpRequest`, this is why you are seeing that error.

The solution is to run the angular app off a web server, e.g. [**Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdRCTYeSEwM1EVt576OS)

You can turn off this restriction in Chrome (by launching it with `--disable-web-security`) but this is not recommended.

Comment: I uploaded into a web server, but the server doesn't show me anything. There's no error messages so I don't know if I did a mistake or something.

Comment: @JasterTDCClan can you browse to the index.html page on the web server?

Comment: Yes, but when I click on the links, the page doesn't show anything new.

Comment: @JasterTDCClan It is working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gdRCTYeSEwM1EVt576OS?p=preview

Comment: @JasterTDCClan are you sure you uploaded show-order.html? Are the files all in the same folder? Is the folder configured as a web site or virtual directory? It works fine in the Plnkr here: plnkr.co/edit/gdRCTYeSEwM1EVt576OS?p=preview

Comment: Yes this code works now, I put the same code into another project I'm doing and didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81472/discussion-between-jastertdc-clan-and-donal).

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting:

Failed to load 'file:///Users/ismaelmoral/GitHub/angularjs-controllers/show-order.html'.

Means you're trying to AJAX request a local file, you should probably try running your code inside a web server like Apache or Nginx to get it to work. Otherwise the code looks good.

Comment: All files are in the same directory, but I will try to put my project in a web server.